# Create a visible custom field through metadata api, for api 29.0 or greater

Tags: metadata-api, field-level-security, api-29

I have gone through almost all the previous questions on creating a visible custom field, but none of the posts were helpful to me.

Some provide apex code, some ask to provide ProfileFieldLevelSecurity. But i dont have any idea how to do that?

Can someone help me solving this through an end to end approach. Right now though my metadata calls, I am able to create the field, but the field is invisible.

What can be done to unhide it? Any easy approach with functioning mechanism will be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I think it would be helpful if we understood better what your overarching goal was. What is the requirement that is leading you to try to solve this problem, and solve it in this way?  In general if you deploy a new custom field in conjunction with a profile or permission set that has field-level access turned on for that field you shouldn't have a problem for the users that have that profile or permission set.

Answer (score 2):

Without getting terribly much into code, you need to add profile field level security permissions. By default, the system assumes no access at all whenever a new field, object, class, tab, app, or page is created (this is a non-exhaustive list-- if you can set permissions on it, assume those permissions default to the most restrictive).

First, build your Object files with the new fields, then query for Profile files (say, with `<types><members>*</members><name>Profile</name></types>` in your **package.xml**), and add in your field level security to the Profile files using `<fieldPermissions><editable>false</editable><field>Object__c.Field__c</field><readable>true</readable></fieldPermissions>`.

The reason why you query your profiles first is that some permissions may or may not disappear if you include only profile information, so you should insert them into the existing files. This may also be API version dependent, so you may need to adjust your strategy slightly. Always test using profiles you don't care about (e.g. not Admin.profile to start off with) so you don't accidentally do Something Bad.

If you're using the Metadata REST API, you'll have to go through the process of updating about 10 profiles at a time, while the File-based approach can update many (or all) profiles at once.